# VisualStudioの画面で縦スライドバーがしっかり現れておらず操作性悪いので対策したい

Tags: visual-studio

標題の件、大した問題ではないのですが開発作業に時間を費やす要因にもなるので教えてください。VisualStudioがインストールされた端末を複数有しておりますが、その1台だけ
各種言語をコーディングするためのページが、以下添付画像のとおり縦スライドバーが現れていない同様の状況にあります。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
目的のコーディング部分までたどり着くまで時間を要してしまう問題を抱えているので、どうにかそろそろ対策を投じたいところです。
何かの設定をちょっと変えるだけで、元に戻るでしょうか？

お手すきで対策をご認識の方　ご教示をよろしくお願い申し上げます。

Comment: エディターウィンドウをフロート表示に切り替えるなどしてもこの状態なのでしょうか。

Comment: @pgrho ご見解をありがとう御座います、状況に変わりありませんでした。